# Unable to Convert Chi-Squared Values into a Numeric Column in R

Tags: r, statistics

I've been working on a project for a little bit for a homework assignment and I've been stuck on a logistical problem for a while now.

What I have at the moment is a list that returns 10000 values in the format:

```
[[10000]]
X-squared 
0.1867083
```

(This is the 10000th value of the list)

What I really would like is to just have the chi-squared value alone so I can do things like create a histogram of the values.

Is there any way I can do this? I'm fine with repeating the test from the start if necessary.

My current code is:

```
nsims = 10000

for (i in 1:nsims) {cancer.cells <- c(rep("M",24),rep("B",13))
malig[i] <- sum(sample(cancer.cells,21)=="M")}

benign = 21 - malig
rbenign = 13 - benign
rmalig = 24 - malig

for (i in 1:nsims) {test = cbind(c(rbenign[i],benign[i]),c(rmalig[i],malig[i]))
cancerchi[i] = chisq.test(test,correct=FALSE) }
```

It gives me all I need, I just cannot perform follow-up analysis on it such as creating a histogram.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Have you tried `as.data.frame(unlist(cancerchi))`?

Comment: Its difficult to reproduce your code without `malig`, what is it? have you tried `unlist()`?

Comment: Thanks guys: malig is just a list of 10000 values that were part of a contingency table. We had to calculate 10000 possible values of malig and then use them to find three other values in a table with 1 degree of freedom. The unlist command seemed to help, but when I try to use something like `cancerdata = as.data.frame(unlist((cancerchi))` and `hist(cancerdata)` it continues to tell me the values are not numeric. Thanks for the help, though - I'm sorry I'm so clueless.

Comment: Try `hist(unlist(cancerchi))` or `hist(as.data.frame(unlist(cancerchi)))`. `hist(cancerchi)` won't work because `cancerchi` is still a list, unless you reassign it (i.e. `cancerchi <- as.data.frame(unlist(cancerchi))`)

Comment: The first one worked perfectly - thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe one of you guys should write it up as an answer?

Comment: Sorry - not quite sure I understand - would you like me to post the original question and answer?

Comment: @user3007495 The suggestion was for someone to post an answer rather than leave the question without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide an answer at the suggestion of @Dr. Mike.

`hist` requires a vector as input.  The reason that `hist(cancerchi)` will not work is because `cancerchi` is a list, not a vector.

There a several ways to convert `cancerchi`, from a list into a format that `hist` can work with.  Here are 3 ways:

```
hist(as.data.frame(unlist(cancerchi)))
```

Note that if you do not reassign `cancerchi` it will still be a list and cannot be passed directly to `hist`.

```
# i.e
class(cancerchi)
hist(cancerchi) # will still give you an error
```

If you reassign, it can be another type of object:

```
(class(cancerchi2 <- unlist(cancerchi)))
(class(cancerchi3 <- as.data.frame(unlist(cancerchi))))

# using the ldply function in the plyr package
library(plyr)
(class(cancerchi4 <- ldply(cancerchi)))
```

these new objects can be passed to `hist` directly

```
hist(cancerchi2)
hist(cancerchi3[,1]) # specify column because cancerchi3 is a data frame, not a vector
hist(cancerchi4[,1]) # specify column because cancerchi4 is a data frame, not a vector
```

A little extra information:  other useful commands for looking at your objects include `str` and `attributes`.